# Multi-dimensional array in C++ , a mystery to me :(

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having lots of problem understanding multidimensional arrays.  Let an array be

```
x[2]; // now x is constant pointer to first element i.e x's name is address of x[0]
```

Now two dimensional array:

```
x[2][5]; // here x is address of x[0] which contains the address of first element of array x[][0];
```

Now the pointer

```
int(*y)[5];
```

is a pointer to array 5 of integers.  How is it possible to write `y = x`?

Now I was doing some practical to understand this in VS, which is here, and my main question is in the image:

http://img184.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=96382_first_122_1120lo.jpg

Please answer the question conceptually; how C++ stores multi-dimensional array, etc.

I'll appreciate any help a lot :)

Comment: Please read http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: You may want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/) about using arrays in C++ ;)

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, a multidimensional array is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.

I think the main cause for misunderstanding is the concept of any array being actually a pointer. But it's not strictly true. An array is a variable that holds a fixed size contiguous collection of elements of the same type. So when you declare an array like `int x[2]` you are declaring a variable that holds two integers. Note that it doesn't hold any pointer.

Now the root of this common misunderstanding is that in C/C++ an array name *evaluates* to the address of its first element and therefore can be used as a pointer. In other words, when you write `x`, you implicitly mean `&x` or `&x[0]`. This was probably done to make expressions more readable.

A multi-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays. In other words, the same logic applies to them, there is nothing special. You read C/C++ declaration starting from the name and going outside, applying modifiers as you encounter them, first [] and (), then *, then type, so you interpret a multi-dimensional array like this (order of reading specified explicitly):

```
int              x      [                2]         [           5];
6. "of type int" 1. "x" 2. "is an array" 3. "of 2". 4. "arrays" 5. "of 5 elements"
```

So there is no such thing as multi-dimensional arrays in C/C++, but there is such thing as one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays. As per the rules for one-dimensional arrays, `x`, `&x` and `&x[0]` all evaluate to the address of the first element. But since the first element is an array, `x[0]` evaluates to the address of that array, that is, the address of its first element which is an int. The same goes for `&x[0]` and `&x[0][0]`. That's why the value of `x[0]` is the same of its address - because `x[0]` is an array.

Note that while these things evaluate to the same address, they have different types. `x` is a pointer to an array of 5 ints, as well as `&x[0]`, as both of them evaluate to the address of the first element of x. `x[0]` evaluates to the address of the first element of `x[0]`, so it's a pointer to int, the same goes for `&x[0][0]`. This example compiles fine and prints the same address for all 4 pointers:

```
  int x[2][5];
  int (*y1)[5] = x;
  int *y2 = x[0];
  int (*y3)[5] = &x[0];
  int *y4 = &x[0][0];
  printf("%p %p %p %p\n", y1, y2, y3, y4);
```

Now, there are different memory layouts for arrays used in different languages. For example, for a two-dimensional array you can group elements by rows or by columns. In C/C++, since there are no "true" multi-dimensional arrays, the memory layout is defined implicitly by the rules above. Since `int x[2][5]`, which can be thought of as a two-dimensional array having 2 rows and 5 columns, actually is an array of 2 arrays, each of which represents a row, you get the "group by rows" layout, which is presented in shybovycha's answer.

Note that it is also possible to create an array of pointers and use it as a multi-dimensional array. The differences to "usual" multi-dimensional arrays are:

1. An array of pointers actually holds pointers inside. That is, addresses of the first elements of sub-arrays.
2. Memory layout isn't contiguous. Each sub-array can be allocated anywhere, for example using malloc() or new[].
3. Sub-arrays can be of different size.

The advantage of this approach is that you can use this array as a pointer to pointer (for example, `int **y`), which makes all multi-dimensional arrays of this kind compatible between each other, even if they have different sizes. But the sizes have to be stored separately in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Look: any multi-dimensional array is the array of arrays. E.g. `x[2][5]` will be equal to this table:

`x[0][0]` `x[0][1]` `x[0][2]` `x[0][3]` `x[0][4]`

`x[1][0]` `x[1][1]` `x[1][2]` `x[1][3]` `x[1][4]`

Pointer assignment would be exactly the same: `x[0]` is the first row in your `2x5` table, so `int *y = x[0]` or `int *y = x[1]` will copy the **address** of first row to `y`.

But if you do `int (*y) = x` then it stores address of `x[0][0]` into `y` variable (`int y` creates an `int` instance while `int (*y)` gives you address of this instance).

**UPD:** Let us have `int **x` variable. It does not matter which size it has. Just take this as a truth that `x`, `x[0]` and `x[0][0]` would provide you with the same address. This could be explained like `Pointer name means its address. Multi-dimensional array is a pointer to pointer. Its name means address of pointer it's pointing on which means address of the last pointer' first element.` (sorry for complicity).

Answer (score 3):

As the name of one-dimensional array is considered to be the pointer to the first element, the construction x[0] is the **pointer** to first array of your 2d array, and x[1] is the pointer to your second array. So, just think of x[0] as it is the name of your 1st array. Adding another pair of brackets (like x[0][0]) will return you the value of the element. And the address of the first element would be &x[0][0] or simply x[0].